# i am very confused on what's wrong on line 16. balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;

Tags: contract-development, remix, ether, compilation, ide

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint)public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint))public allowance;

    int public totalSupply = 10000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "JeddCoin";
    string public symbol = "JEDD";
    uint public decimals = 18;

   event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
   event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint 
value);

   constructor() {
       balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
   } 

   function balanceOf(address owner)public view returns(uint){
   return balances[owner];
   }

   function transfer(address to, uint value)public returns(bool){
       require(balanceOf(msg.sender)>= value, 'balance too low');
       balances[to] += value;
       balances[msg.sender] -= value;
       emit Transfer (msg.sender, to, value);
       return true;
   
   }
   function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public 
returns(bool) {
       require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
       require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
       balances[to] += value;
       balances[from] -= value;
       emit Transfer(from, to, value);
       return true;
   }

   function aprove(address spender, uint value)public returns(bool){
       allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
       emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `uint` vs `int`

Comment: how do i convert int to uint

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mix `uint` with `int`: `totalSupply` is of type `int` while `balances` maps to `uint`.

Since your `totalSupply` can't ever be under zero, you should simply change that to be `uint`. That way you don't have to convert anything and your types are more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared `balances` as `uint` in line 4, `totalSupply` should also have the type `uint`.

Change the 7th line to `uint public totalSupply = 10000 * 10 ** 18;` and it will not show the error.